# Using soap services(.asmx) with Azure Service fabric

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I am migrating my existing services to Azure service fabric. My existing application support the soap service(asmx) for the legacy users. I want to use the same web service as part of my microservice. That web service test.asmx(say) can be called from Rest Apis as well(If soln is there). But I'm not finding any way to use the soap service as part of Azure service fabric microservice approach. Help me out of possible solutions for tackling the web service scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [converting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738697(v=vs.110).aspx) your ASMX service into a WCF service with a BasicHttpBinding. You can then host your WCF service inside a stateless SF service, like shown [here](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.WcfCalc).

```
private static ICommunicationListener CreateRestListener(StatelessServiceContext context)
{
   string host = context.NodeContext.IPAddressOrFQDN;
   var endpointConfig = context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetEndpoint("CalculatorEndpoint");
   int port = endpointConfig.Port;
   string scheme = endpointConfig.Protocol.ToString();
   string uri = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}://{1}:{2}/", scheme, host, port);
   var listener = new WcfCommunicationListener<ICalculatorService>(
                    serviceContext: context,
                    wcfServiceObject: new WcfCalculatorService(),
                    listenerBinding: new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None),
                    address: new EndpointAddress(uri)
   );
   return listener;
}
```